# Как определить сколько пользователей просматривает раздел на форуме (Yii2)?

Tags: php, yii2

Делаю небольшой форум на Yii2 и возникла задача подсчитать количество пользователей, просматривающих тот или иной раздел на форуме.
Можете подсказать как это правильнее реализовать?

Comment: Яндекс метрика или гугл аналитикс уже "те"?

Comment: Интересует реализация без постоянного обращения к API GA, К тому же количество пользователей просматривающих раздел в n-ый момент времени должны считаться исходя из просмотров данного раздела, его подразделов и топиков в них. Я не уверен, что через GA получится сделать такое